# Forgot password--- show the rules for that passphrase?

Tags: password, password-reminder

I know there's been a lot of discussion about password strength and indicators when signing up. I often find that when I forget a password for a site, its because I can't remember which set of rules were in place for that site (ie, >10 chars, special chars, no numbers) and if I knew those rules, Id remember which algorithm I used for my password.

To me, it seems like it's worth giving the user a hint about what the password rules were, before forcing them to go through the whole forgot password process. I'm finally able to implement something like this on our site, but I was curious about the UX of it.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0IzL4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

With that said, has anyone seen this done in practice/know of a reason not too?

**Edit 1:**

I've often thought the argument against this falls under the vague umbrella of *security*-- "If we display this information it will be easier to crack the password"-- but I can obtain the same information by attempting to create a new account

Comment: Microsoft at least does (sort of)--if you enter a password longer than 16 (which they infuriatingly don't auto-truncate for you) it at least warns "hey enter just the first 16 characters". Unrelated, but don't limit your passwords to 16 characters.

Comment: Interesting! That's *tangentially* what I'm after. If you don't allow special characters, tell me that when I try to enter a password with a special char, instead of just telling me the password is "invalid"

Comment: See this question: [Would it be bad design (and unsafe) to put password guidelines next to a login box?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/would-it-be-bad-design-and-unsafe-to-put-password-guidelines-next-to-a-login-b/16329#16329)

Comment: Well, that settles it. I searched for awhile before posting, but it looks like this is a repeat of that question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is quite a long shot to expect users to remember their passwords base on the password complexity requirements.
I don't think this would be a security issue though, since hackers could just go to the signup page and find out from there what the requirements for passwords are.

On the other hand, I know that when I forget a password it's sometimes because the website has asked for an unusually complex password. In that case I need to change my usual password (bad practice but that's what people do).
So when possible, I would try and stick to something that is a standard : min 8 characters, at least one number, at least one letter.
But again it might now be sufficient for banking sites, etc.

Comment: For me, it's much easier to recall the password when I know the rules. Many sites have no requirements on password strength, therefore I'm always surprised that on one specific site I have a stronger password than I would likely use if the restrictions did not exist.